# How to get value from type

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have this type

```
type Card = (CardValue,Suite)
```

I want to write a function to show color based on `Card.Suite` value

```
colour :: Card -> Colour
colour card = if card.Suite == Spades then Red else Black
```

This code just illustrates what I want to achieve. I don't know how to actually get suite value from `Card(CardValue,Suite)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `type` keyword declares a new type synonim, not a new type. In your code a `Card` is just a tuple of `CardValue` and `Suite`.

To access pair's elements either use `fst` and `snd`:

```
colour card = if snd card == Spades then Red else Black
```

or pattern-match the argument:

```
colour (value,suite) = if suite == Spades then Red else Black
```

Answer (score 5):

`type Card = (CardValue, Suit)` makes `Card` a type alias for a tuple of `CardValue` and `Suit` data. That might not be the best data structure (a `data` member using record syntax seems better) but it's trivial to do what you want:

```
data Suit  = Spades | Clubs | Hearts | Diamonds
data Color = Red | Black

type Card  = (CardValue, Suit)

getSuitColor :: Card -> Color
getSuitColor (_, Spades) = Black
getSuitColor (_, Clubs)  = Black
getSuitColor _           = Red
```

Or you could use guards to do the same

```
getSuitColor :: Card -> Color
getSuitColor (_, suit)
  | suit == Spades = Black
  | suit == Clubs  = Black
  | otherwise      = Red
```

However you'll have to use `deriving Eq` on your `Suit` to do that (since otherwise you can't `==` it!)

---

If this were me I'd probably use that record syntax I mentioned above

```
data Card { rank :: CardValue
          , suit :: Suit
          }
```

Which then means you have to construct your `Card`s, as they're separate types.

```
myOldCard = (3, Spades)
myNewCard = Card 3 Spades
```

But it means you have ready-made lookups into them.

```
getColor :: Card -> Color
getColor = determineColor . suit
  where
  determineColor :: Suit -> Color
  determineColor Spades = Black
  determineColor Clubs  = Black
  determineColor _      = Red
```